# Matplotlib: Scatterplot and heatmap in the same plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a scatterplot and heatmap in the same plot. 
The scatterplot is as follows:

```
examples, targets  = zip(*list(blue_data()))
examples2, targets2  = zip(*list(red_data()))
plt.plot(np.array(examples), np.array(targets), 'o', color = 'b')
plt.plot(np.array(examples2), np.array(targets2), 'o', color = 'r')
```

The above works just fine. I also want to do a heatmap. It works just fine, if I do it in a separate subplot. However, I want to try to do both on the same plot, sharing the same axes and am unsure how to do it. This is the code for the heatmap:

```
x = np.linspace(lower_x, upper_x, 100)
y = np.linspace(lower_y, upper_y, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.zeros((x.size,y.size))
for ii in range(len(x)):
    for jj in range(len(y)):
        X_ = X[ii,jj];
        Y_ = Y[ii,jj];
        Z[ii,jj] = some_function(X_,Y_)
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'b'])
bounds = [-100,0,100]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
plt.imshow(Z,cmap= cmap, norm = norm, extent = [-lower_x,upper_x,-lower_y,upper_y], origin = 'lower');
```

How can I combine the two plots so that they appear on the same plot with aligned axes?

Comment: Have you tried simply calling both `imshow` and the `plot` functions?